# Is there a boss in the Bottom of the Well?

Tags: zelda-ocarina-of-time

I'm in the Bottom of the Well dungeon in *The Legend of Zelda: Ocarina of Time*. I've found every chest shown by the Compass, but I still don't have a Boss Key, and I can't for the life of me guess where the boss room would be anyway. Is there simply no boss in this dungeon?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no boss-key/proper boss, but there is a mini-boss that gives you an important item from a big chest.

If you're not sure whether you've got that far, there's a brief guide to the dungeon [here](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Bottom_of_the_Well#Dungeon) which tells you what the mini-boss and item are.